# How to use if/else in request class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

**i using only one page for "create ads page".** 
**How to use multiple Validation Rules for query('type')?** 
**ads.blade.php**

```
@if ($request->query('type') == 'text')

   //fields

@elseif($request->query('type') == 'post')

   //fields

@elseif($request->query('type') == 'banner')

   //fields

@endif
```

**AdsRequest.php**

```
public function rules(Request $request)
{

    //this if not work. how to resolve?

    if ($request->query('type') == 'text'){
        return [
            'title'  => ['required','max:255', Rule::unique('ads')->ignore($this->route('ad'))],
            'url' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required|in:text,banner,post,sidebar',
            'status' => 'nullable',
            'btn' => 'nullable',
            'pic' => 'nullable',
            'description' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

**How to use multiple Validation Rules for query('type')?**

Comment: This question will be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696091/laravel-5-4-how-to-use-multiple-error-messages-for-the-same-custom-validation

Comment: Would you suggest I use Cutom Servive Provider?

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand this article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a request class, you can access the received data by the `all()` method.

```
$data = $this->all();
$type = isset($data['type'])? $data['type'] : null;

switch($type) {
     case "text": 
        return [
           'url' => 'required'
        ]
}
```

Note that what you return in the `rules()` method is a normal PHP array that can be a merge of different arrays. You may have some rules that are regardless of this `type` field.

```
$commonRules = [
   'title' => 'required',
   'email' => 'required|email',
];
$specificRules = [];

$data = $this->all();
$type = isset($data['type'])? $data['type'] : null;

switch($type) {
     case "text": 
        $specificRules = [
           'url' => 'required',
        ];
        break;

     case "foo":
        $specificRules = [
            'btn' => 'nullable',
        ];
        break;
}

return array_merge($commonRules, $specificRules);
```